# Problem with Capture Screeshot API PageSpeed Insight

Tags: php, google-apis-explorer

Problem with Capture Screeshot API PageSpeed Insight
I saw answers, but I have always a problem.
My probleme is:

> Warning: base64_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp64\www... it's this line=> $decoded = base64_decode($googlePagespeedData);

I dont know convert array in string, because I don’t know critères choose. JSON is composed several array in array.
I would want to get Capture, but I don't arrived.
Can you help me, please ?

The code :

```
$siteURL  =  "http://www.perdu.com";
$googlePagespeedData = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=$siteURL&screenshot=true"), true);
var_dump($googlePagespeedData);
$googlePagespeedData = str_replace(array('_', '-'), array('/', '+'), $googlePagespeedData);
$decoded = base64_decode($googlePagespeedData);
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,{$googlePagespeedData}\"alt=\"Screenshot\" />";
```

Sorry to my langage, I learn english.

thanks,

Comment: `$decoded` does not contain what you think it does; it's not a string, but an array. Dump out its value and figure out which bit you need.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
How do I know which criteria to choose?
I have to do a foreach for each table and select each criteria?
Sorry, I don't understand.